# WPF MEF and 3rd party library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ninject, mef

I have 3rd party dll and in this dll is such hierarchy: class Node realize interface INode. This dll uses Ninject binding in it. My application uses this dll and  Prism and MEF as IoC container. I haven't practice in Prism and MEF before, so one thing I want to do is to bind INode to Node. 
I don't have access to INode and Node, so write smth like that I can't:

```
[Export(typeof(INode))]
class Node : INode{...}
```

In Ninject I would did it in such way:

```
Bind<INode>().To<Node>();
```

Can I do something like that in MEF? Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MEF's Convention Model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hammett/2011/03/08/mefs-convention-model/). You can use it for exporting types you don't control. For example:

```
var registration = new RegistrationBuilder();
registration.ForType<Node>().Export<INode>();
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Node).Assembly, registration);
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Another way would be to inherit `Node` in your own code and export it:

```
[Export(typeof(INode))]
class MyNode : Node { }
```